# Best strategy for sending commands to Arduino: Send UDP packet OR get configuration from a dynamic web page?

Tags: php, logging, udp, command, arduino

I would like to send some configuration parameters to an Arduino Ethernet board, and I came up with two potential solutions. I would be grateful if you could give your thoughts on using either one of those.

The first (obvious) option is to send a [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) command containing the configuration to the Arduino. This, however, requires a reconfiguration for most routers to enable port-forwarding or disabling the firewall.

So my second option is to get the configuration by accessing a web page from Ardino which will contain all the required information (this will be updated using a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) script on the server). This page will be checked every minute or so and update the configuration if a new one is found. The requirement for communication every minute is not a problem since there is also traffic on the other direction (my Arduino logs temperatures in a web site).

Which method is the best and are there any pitfalls I should avoid?

Answer (score 0):

I recently finished my [WebPlayer.ino](http://mpflaga.github.com/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_web_player_8ino_source.html) where it got pushed commands over the web as to what files to play from the SD card to the MP3 chip, along with volume and speed control. Similar to your goals, I had to pull a bunch of pieces from all over into it. So it may be a nice example of how to parse the web commands.

In either UDP or TCP and using the native Ethernet library, one needs to read the character string from the `ethernet.client`. Regardless of direction and TCP vs UDP. The one advantage I have seen with UDP is that there are some examples using the "String" type to get the data as a whole, but that is insignificant. I would stick with TCP, look at my example as how to read the web servers requests.

Additionally, the [Webduino](http://code.google.com/p/webduino/) library is a wrapper that simplifies getting the commands. It provides [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and the like. So that would be very useful for what your doing. But it uses a huge chunk of RAM and ROM. Hence my project did not use it.